# Find the degree of the splitting field in $\Bbb C$ of $f(x)=x^4-8x^2+15$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

This is a biquadratic polynomial with roots $\pm \sqrt{3}$ and $\pm\sqrt{5}$. So, the splitting field is $\Bbb Q(\pm\sqrt{3}, \pm\sqrt{5})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$. For the degree part, can I conclude that since this polynomial is irreducible in $\Bbb Q$ that the degree is $4$?

Say for example, that I didn't know about tha result, then how would I go about proving it? I am aware of the tower law, but not sure how to utilise it properly in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe that you meant $x^4-8x^2+15$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant $+15$ as the $c$ term.

Comment: $x^4-8x^2+15=(x^2-3)(x^2-5)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degree is indeed $4$, but not because the polynomial is irreducible:
$$
x^4-8x^2+15=(x^2-3)(x^2-5)
$$
The degree can be computed by noting that
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})]=2
$$
because $\sqrt{5}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ (prove it).

Comment: But the roots of $x^4-8x^2+15$ have no roots in the rationals - so isn't the polynomial irreducible? We have $$\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}=\{a+b\sqrt{3}: a,b\in\Bbb Q\},$$ and so, the only way to obtain $\sqrt{5}$ from this is if we let $a=0$ and $b=\sqrt{5}/\sqrt{3}$ which is not a rational number so $\sqrt{5}\not\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$. Is the right track? Why does this imply that the degree of that is $2$ though?

Comment: @thesmallprint “No root = irreducible” only holds for polynomials of degree 2 and 3. Since a factorization *can* be exhibited, the polynomial is reducible. For the proof, suppose $(a+b\sqrt{3})^2=5$ and find a contradiction. Since $\sqrt{5}$ is a root of $x^2-5$ which has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, its degree is either 1 or 2; it cannot be 1, so it's 2.

Comment: Thank you for this, this has helped a lot. One final question - having derived the contradiction, why must it follow that the degree cannot be $1$?

Comment: @thesmallprint An element of degree $1$ over the field $F$ belongs to $F$.

Comment: Thank you very much!